# Change management of aerial photos of same fields

Tags: aerial-photography, change-detection

I am looking for an automated solution with capable to stitch aerial photographs and the result can be integrated into Google Maps. Furthermore it has an ability to show discrepancies on a new layer from photos taken  different points in time. For this demands which GIS software could be a solution? Possible to automate this workflow?